# Add Field giving ERROR 000464: Cannot get exclusive schema lock

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, fields-attributes, schema-locks, error-000464

I'm doing an interface using ArcMap 10.2 and Python scripts that run at Python window.
For each time that my script run, I need to update information, so I think that I need to delete originals tables and create news.

When I try to do this with ExcelToTable  it gives me an error to add field:

```
arcpy.env.workspace = "F:\Otim\inter"
arcpy.Delete_management(c_re) #delete layer
c_re=arcpy.ExcelToTable_conversion("02_Rea.xlsx", "cg1_re_otim.dbf", "Rea_L")
#arcpy.env.workspace = "F:ArcGIS\Trab\Model\Result"
arcpy.AddField_management(c_re, "Name_Ba", "Text", 50, "", "", "refcode", "NULLABLE", "REQUIRED")
arcpy.AddField_management(c_re, "Longitude", "Float", "", "", "9", "", "NON_NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")
arcpy.AddField_management(c_re, "Latitude", "Float", "", "", "9", "", "NON_NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")
```

> ERROR 000464: Cannot get exclusive schema lock.  Either being edited
> or in use by another application. Failed to execute (AddField).

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing:

```
c_re=arcpy.ExcelToTable_conversion("02_Rea.xlsx", "cg1_re_otim.dbf", "Rea_L")
```

to:

```
c_re = "cg1_re_otim.dbf"
arcpy.ExcelToTable_conversion("02_Rea.xlsx", c_re, "Rea_L")
```

The way you had it is setting your variable `c_re` to a Result object rather than a string representing a dBase file name, which is what the Add Field tool expects.

Comment: It gives another error:
Runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<string>", line 61, in <module>   File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\conversion.py", line 44, in ExcelToTable     raise e ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid. ERROR 000725: Output Table: Dataset F:\Otimizacao\interface\cg1_reactiva_otimizada.dbf already exists. Failed to execute (ExcelToTable).

Comment: That's a new problem so should be researched/asked as a new question, using the new code snippet to illustrate precisely what you ran and the error you received from that code snippet.